# What is this /tmp/*/timingsafe crash?

Tags: macos, crash

I've got this weird crash of `/private/tmp/*/timingsafe` which doesn't exist invoked from `sh` parent process which also doesn't exist. Here are the details:

```
Process:               timingsafe [99822]
Path:                  /private/tmp/*/timingsafe
Identifier:            timingsafe
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        sh [99814]
Responsible:           timingsafe [99822]
User ID:               501
...
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
...
Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _timingsafe_bcmp
  Referenced from: /private/tmp/*/timingsafe
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   dyld                            0x000000011aaf567e __abort_with_payload + 10
1   dyld                            0x000000011aaf50af abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 90
2   dyld                            0x000000011aaf50f1 abort_with_payload + 9
3   dyld                            0x000000011aad06d3 dyld::halt(char const*) + 361
4   dyld                            0x000000011aad07de dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 139
5   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffa7be148e dyld_stub_binder + 282
6   ???                             0x000000010ce15028 0 + 4511060008
7   timingsafe                      0x000000010ce000ca main + 59
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffa7be5255 start + 1
...
Binary Images:
       0x10cdff000 -        0x10ce14ff3 +timingsafe (0) <5D6C9416-6EDF-3FA4-A920-1727D3E4BDA7> /tmp/*/timingsafe
       0x11aacc000 -        0x11ab091c7  dyld (421.1) <A525EAEA-AF86-30C2-B360-3D093B4F0828> /usr/lib/dyld
...
```

Above says that `_timingsafe_bcmp` symbol is not found (see: `man timingsafe_bcmp`), but I'm not quiet sure what exactly crashed and why it points to the file which doesn't exist.

Any idea what is this `/tmp/*/timingsafe` and how to deal with such error? Is it a macOS Sierra bug or some kind of malware?

Comment: I hope you are not at DefCon